# Are my questions premoderated, why does it take them a few minutes to show up?

Tags: support

Are my questions premoderated, why does it take them a few minutes to show up?

Thanks for any reply :-)

Comment: I had noticed this too on other sites - the answer is most likely caching. If you're looking at [this page](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/), it's cached for some amount of minutes, but the ["newest" tab](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) should be pretty quick. Rest assured there is no pre-moderation feature on SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any are premoderated; not by a human moderator anyway.

If I post a question of my own (on any site), I think I found that maybe it takes a minute or so (not a few minutes) to show on the [sort by Active view](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active), but that it appears more quickly on the [sort by Newest view](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)?

I'm not sure my observation is correct; but if it is, and if that was implemented on purpose, and if I had to guess why that's so, it would be because a question jumps to the top of the Active view each time it's edited, so they give the author of a question some time (i.e. a delay) in which to edit the new question immediately after it's posted, during which it's not at the top of the Active view.

Editing a question to 'bump' it to the top of the Active queue is seen as poor etiquette (on high-traffic sites) if it's done too frequently -- [Purposeful Question Bumping: Abuse or feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4397/139866)

To get a second opinion I'd recommend you post on https://meta.stackexchange.com except that you might not get a good answer there either ... the closest topic I found there was [Newest questions appear with delay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197779/139866) which was closed as `status-norepro` (i.e. Stack Exchange haven't reproduced the bug, don't understand the bug report, and/or think that it doesn't usually happen).